# Wrong file size shown when use Mode="Server" in ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have used Ajaxtoolkit file upload control in my c#.net application(web forms). Below is the code which I have used to generate control in page

```
<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload Enabled="true" ID="fileUpload" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="ajaxfileUpload" Mode="Server" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload>
```

The issue is, when I upload file with any size, it still shows it as 20.00 bytes, which can be seen as below

[image]

The strange thing is when I update the mode to "Auto", it is showing the file size correctly.

Comment: Why don't you always choose `Auto`?

Comment: @MikhailTymchukDX I don't want to upload the files as soon as user selects them. My requirement is to submit all documents along with other form details at once, hence I have user Mode as Server

Comment: Then you need to set the `AutoStartUpload` property to `true`. The `Mode` property does nothing with the autoupload.